# Node.js - Run tests against Windows and Linux on the same machine

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, windows, testing

I'd like to run automated tests in a Windows environment as well as a Linux environment.

Is spinning up a virtual machine the only way or are there some kind of emulators? E.g. a library that patches a Linux Node.js install to simulate windows paths such as `C:\Program Files\My Project\script.js`.

Comment: One thing to consider is that if you use emulation, you're not testing your target environment, you're testing the emulator. *Maybe* that's good enough for some cases, but...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes. In my case that'd be good enough for now. I'd like to avoid complexifying my setup with VMs for now.

Comment: Take a look at WSL, Windows Subsystem for Linux.

Comment: @Philippe Neat- is there something for the other way around? I'm on Linux.

Comment: Yes, https://www.winehq.org/